# Rails Console output breaks when modifying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, irb, pry

Totally lacking intuition here.
First i thought i only happens when copying and pasting code from editor. Unfortunately it's more common. Only thing I am doing is trying to insert more code somewhere in the middle of current input or modifying it.

**Expected behavior:**

- Modify input without side effects.

**What actually happens:**

- VERY OFTEN when modifying input it gets messed up.
- If that happens every key press will copy and insert current input alongside with pressed character.

**Vital notes:**

- Encoding is set to UTF-8 in terminal(s)
- Issue persists on different emulators ( Terminator, gnome-terminal )
- Issue persists when using different Ruby runtime console ( IRB, Pry )
- Issue appears to be related to Ruby runtime, NOT Linux shell (i guess...)

**Issue appears since:**

- Since system install. Didn't appear on my MacBook Air

**System:**

- ArchLinux, although coworker reported same thing happens on his MacBook Pro.

**How to reproduce (works for me):**

- Open rails console
- Type example code: Shift.where(name: "som").where(name: "dom").where(name: "pom")
- Navigate cursor to modify first where statement.
- Change "som" to "SOM"
- Should see it break
- Press random key repeatedly to see it break even more.

**Images:**

- Good input

[image]

- Now i will navigate to first where statement to change "som" to uppercase "SOM"
- I basically navigated my cursor and pressed SHIFT+S, SHIFT+O, SHIFT+M

[image]

Hope it's clear enough :-)
Thank you!

---

**EDIT 1:**

- Tried using zsh instead of bash, didn't help
- Disabled spring gem, didn't help

**EDIT 2:**

Folks on reddit suggested that i should check if there are any Ruby readline warnings eg. "Readline is not installed". None of them appear anywhere. Also reinstalled ruby 2.4.1, seems like it's not the problem in my case.

**EDIT 3:**

**I cannot reproduce the issue in a different Rails project**.
Issue appears on Rails **5.1.1**, meanwhile **5.0.3** works flawlessly.
Is it possible that Rails itself (or rather one of its gems) can be the cause?

Comment: It could be useful to tell us which _shell_ you use. I remember to have experienced similar issues (macos) but it didn't happen now for a long time - maybe since I started using `zsh`.
Another question: How do you navigate your cursor the specified place? With your mouse cursor or with the keyboard (in the latter case, do you go char by char or do you use some jump-whole-word mechanic and does this maybe make a difference?)?

Comment: Works fine in GNOME Terminal 3.18.3 on ubuntu 16.04 LTS running ruby 2.3.1p112 and Rails 4.2.1.

Comment: Are you using the Spring gem? It's known to interfere with console output in some cases. Uncomment the Spring gem from your Gemfile, and kill any Spring jobs in the background. Then retest.

Comment: You might also want to look at which terminal emulation your terminal is configured to use. I'd try different common ones to see if the behavior changes.

Comment: @JaySchneider I am using bash. Both jump-whole-word and char produce same result. Also in hope installed zsh but it didn't help :-( So same results on zsh.

Comment: @Casper I disabled spring. Didn't help.

Comment: Guys! Do you think there is any chance that rails itself (or rather one of its subgems) i causing the issue? I switched over to a new project i work on and it seems like issue is not present there. It's quite hard to believe, i will do some more testing and come back with the results.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue, and I boiled it down to my coloring.

I had the following in my IRBRC:

```
class String

  def _colorize(color_code)
    "\e[#{color_code}m#{self}\e[0m"
  end

  def red
    _colorize(31)
  end

  def yellow
    _colorize(33)
  end
end

IRB.conf[:PROMPT][:MY_PROMPT] = {
  :AUTO_INDENT => true,            # enables auto-indent mode
  :PROMPT_I => "[ME]".red + " > ".yellow,               # normal prompt
  :PROMPT_S => "[ME]".red + "   ".yellow,               # prompt for continuated strings
  :PROMPT_C => "[ME]".red + " * ".yellow,               # prompt for continuated statement
  :RETURN =>   "[ME]".red + "=> ".yellow + "%s\n".red        # format to return value
}
IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE] = :MY_PROMPT
```

And when I removed the `.red` and `.yellow`, everything was just fine.

I think it's because my coloring characters like `\e[31m` was getting counted as a length 5 characters instead of 0 characters.

My solution was to remove my coloring for the time being. Hopefully someone will come up with a better solution than that.